# Questions on $A^mBA^n=I$ and $\small B=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&-1&3&1\\1&1&2&1\\2&-1&3&2\\-1&-2&1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-calculus, solution-verification

Let $m,n\in \mathbb N$ and $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ so that:
$$A^mBA^n=I$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix} \;1&-1&\;3&\;1\\\;1&\;1&\;2&\;1\\\;2&-1&\;3&\;2\\-1&-2&\;1&\;2\end{bmatrix}$$
$(a)$ Is $A$ regular?

$(b)$ Calculate $A^{m+n}$

$(a)$ $A$ is regular because $\det {(A^mBA^n)}=\det A\cdot\det {(A^{m-1}BA^n)}\ne0$

$(b)$ $A^{m+n}=A^mIA^n=A^m(B\frac{1}{B})A^n=\frac{1}{B}$

I inverted $B$ *blockwise*.

As on Wikipedia (in notation here I used $B$ for a block-matrix, not to mix itwith the initial matrix): 
$${\begin{bmatrix} A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} A^{-1}+A^{-1}B{(D-CA^{-1}B)}^{-1}CA^{-1} &- A^{-1}B{(D-CA^{-1}B)}^{-1}\\{(D-CA^{-1}B)}^{-1}CA^{-1} & {(D-CA^{-1}B)}^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$$
For the sake of simplicity, I transformed B into upper-triangular matrix:
$$B=\begin{bmatrix} \;1&-1&\;3&\;1\\\;1&\;1&\;2&\;1\\\;2&-1&\;3&\;2\\-1&-2&\;1&\;2\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix} \;1&-1&\;3&\;1\\\;0&\;2&-1&\;0\\0&\;1&-3&\;0\\\;0&-3&\;4&\;3\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix} \;1&-1&\;3&\;1\\\;0&\;0&\;5&\;0\\\;0&\;1&-3&\;0\\\;0&\;0&-5&\;3\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix} \;1&-1&\;3&\;1\\\;0&\;1&-3&\;0\\\;0&\;0&5&\;0\\\;0&\;0&-5&\;3\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix} \;1&-1&\;3&\;1\\\;0&\;1&-3&\;0\\\;0&\;0&\;5&\;0\\\;0&\;0&\;0&\;3\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix} \;1&\;0&\;0&\;1\\\;0&\;1&-3&\;0\\\;0&\;0&\;5&\;0\\\;0&\;0&\;0&\;3\end{bmatrix}$$
/edited: here I could've get $I_4$, but I would like to go through different ways/
$$A=I, B=\begin{bmatrix}\;0&\;1\\-3&\;0\end{bmatrix}, C=0_2,D=\begin{bmatrix}\;5&\;0\\\;0&\;3\end{bmatrix}$$

Then, the *Schur complement of A*: $$D-CA^{-1}B=D$$
I got $$D^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{5}&\;0\\\;0&\frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}$$
Then$$-BD^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\;0&-\frac{1}{3}\\\frac{3}{5}&\;0\end{bmatrix}$$

Finally:
$$B^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\;1&\;0&\;0&\frac{1}{3}\\\;0&\;1&-\frac{3}{5}&0\\\;0&\;0&\frac{1}{5}&\;0\\\;0&\;0&\;0&\frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}$$
This appears to be just a little different than $B$ transformed.
Is this correct?

Comment: Post-multiply $B$ by your supposed $B^{-1}$: you'll get a $1$ in the $(1,2)$-place. So you've made a slip.

Comment: @ancientmathematician May I ask if you see where I've made the slip? So I could rewrite it?

Comment: I don't follow the complicated way you calculate the inverse. And using $B$ in two different ways is mad. Why not just reduce $[B I]$ to $[I B^{-1}]$ by the usual Gauss row-reduction?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I posted one task with that method and one user suggested me to try this, so I wanted to practise a little bit because we haven't learned about neither of them. I see the step where I can continue, but I can't stop thinking about this mistake.

Comment: I believe that the top-right-hand block of your supposed inverse has the wrong sign. But even if you correct that, you've still only got the inverse of the triangular matrix you reduced $B$ to, not the inverse of $B$ itself. Gauss reduction is surely more efficient, and you can do it while thinking about other things.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, O.K., thank you! I see then why it doesnt work. It is better not to waste time then. Thank you once again for the feedback.

Comment: Looking at the formula you say comes from Wikipedia, I don't believe it is true. Look at what you get if you pre-multiply the propose inverse by the original block matrix. The top left block is not $I$. You  need to change the signs of some of the terms, but I can't spot which.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, I saw that after posting, but I checked a few times, but I might have copied something wrong. It is more probable, however, I really checked it.

Comment: $B^{-1}$ is triangular if and only if $B$ is triangular. Therefore your answer is definitely wrong.

Comment: Note that you have an error (or missing step) in the proof when you say $A^{m+n}$ $=A^mIA^n$ $=A^m(BB^{-1})A^n$ $=B^{-1}$; you have no guarantee that $B^{-1}$ commutes with the powers of $A$. Your statement that $A^{m+n}=B^{-1}$ is true, but this isn't enough to show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that $A^{m+n}$ is $B^{-1}$, but your reasoning is incomplete and your numerical answer for $B^{-1}$ is wrong.

You claimed that $A^m(BB^{-1})A^n=B^{-1}$, but why is it true? Since $B^{-1}A^n$ is not necessarily equal to $A^nB^{-1}$, you need to justify the previous equality. One may argue as follows: as $(A^mB)A^n=I$, we have $A^n(A^mB)=I$ as well (because $XY=I$ implies that $YX=I$ for square matrices). Hence $A^{m+n}B=I$, i.e. $A^{m+n}=B^{-1}$.

And your result for $B^{-1}$ is a triangular matrix. This is definitely wrong. In general, for a nonsingular matrix $B$, $B^{-1}$ is triangular if and only if $B$ is triangular, but the $B$ in question is clearly not triangular.